# Как в методе done() взять внешнюю переменую?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть код, в нем `for()` на 2 прохода, для каждого прохода создан массив данных `_vars`. Внутри цикла получаю доступ к этим данным `_vars[i].param`, но вот в `done()` аякса переменная `i = undefined`, конструкция вида `_vars[i]` не пашет. Как быть?

Теоретически в замыкании переменные ищутся во вложенных функция все выше и выше. Тут видимо функция в колбеке и не видна?

**Код**

```
function _init() {

    _loadingImg.show();

    var _dataSend = {},
    _vars = [{action:8, name: 'service'}, {action:7, name: 'town'}];

    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

        _dataSend.action = _vars[i].action;

        $.ajax({
        url: 'query.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: _dataSend
    })
        .done(function(response) {

            var _sel = $('<select></select').attr({
                class: 'chosen-select',
                name: _vars[i].name
            });

            for (var j = 0; j < response.length; j++) {
                _sel.append('<option value="' + response[j].tid + '">' + response[j].name + '</option>')
            }
            $('.box.select').prepend(_sel);

        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        })
        .always(function() {
            $('.chosen-select').chosen();
            _loadingImg.hide();
        });
    }
}
```

И еще вопросик, в методе `always()` есть отключка анимации загрузки `_loadingImg.hide()`, как запускать ее только при условии окончательного выполнения обоих аякс-запросов?

Comment: а точно `i=undefined` а не `i==2` и из-за этого `_vars[i]==undefined` ?

Comment: @Grundy TypeError: _vars[i] is undefined  
в строке name: _vars[i].name

Comment: Ну да :) я про то и говорю - классическая проблема с замыканием и асинхронной функцией

Comment: сейчас в вопросе самом ошибка: _но вот в done() аякса переменная `i = undefined`_ и из-за нее сделан неверный вывод: _тут видимо функция в колбеке и не видна?_

Comment: @Grundy то есть цикл уже выполнился и аякс обращается к i = 2 ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38593/discussion-between-grundy-and-jean-claude).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как яваскрипт однопоточен, то если внутри функции вызывается асинхронная операция, например ajax запрос - обработка его ответа будет осуществляться **после** выхода из основной функции.

Таким образом к моменту выполнения функции `done` - цикл уже закончил свою работу, и значение замкнутой переменной `i` равно 2.

Стандартное решение: использовать IIFE и передать в нее i как параметр

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

    _dataSend.action = _vars[i].action;

    $.ajax({
    url: 'query.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: _dataSend
})
.done(function(index){
    return function(response) {

        var _sel = $('<select></select').attr({
            class: 'chosen-select',
            name: _vars[index].name
        });
        ...
    };}(i));

...
```

---

Что касается второго вопроса: нужно использовать [функцию $.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

Для этого можно собрать аякс запросы в массив и используя `apply` передать его `when`.

Например:

```
var ajaxs = _vars.map(function(el){
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'query.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {action: el.action}
    }).done(...).fail(...);
});

$.when.apply($,ajaxs).always(function() {
    $('.chosen-select').chosen();
    _loadingImg.hide();
});
```

В ES2015 можно использовать [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), тогда запись выгляди более привычно

```
$.when(...ajaxs).always(function() {
    $('.chosen-select').chosen();
    _loadingImg.hide();
});
```

Такой подход необходимо использовать, так как функция `when` не принимает массив.

Comment: ок, спасибо, хотя, конечно, мне пока непонятна конструкция $.when.apply($,ajaxs).

Comment: @Jean-Claude, [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) - аналог [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), за исключением способа передачи параметров, у `call` - они идут списком `f.call(thisArg, a,b,c,d)`, у `apply` - массивом `f.apply(thisArg,[a,b,c,d])`

Comment: да да, ясно, но на практике их пока не использовал.